# terraform-plugin-framework Multiple backend clients

Tags: go, plugins, terraform

I am trying to create a terraform plugin that can configure both Kafka topics and schemas. Unfortunatly the schemas can only be created via a REST API endpoint where as the topics are created via Kafka protocol.
I managed to create a working plugin for schemas fine but now need to extend it to support creating topics as well. However I am unsure how to define that the resource data could come from the different client endpoints.

For example resp.ResourceData should I think include both the original schemaClient and also the new topicClient.

```
func (p *RedPandaProvider) Configure(ctx context.Context, req provider.ConfigureRequest, resp *provider.ConfigureResponse) {
    var data RedPandaProviderModel

    resp.Diagnostics.Append(req.Config.Get(ctx, &data)...)

    if resp.Diagnostics.HasError() {
        return
    }

    apiURL := data.SchemaApiUrl.ValueString()
    bootstrapServers := data.BootstrapServers.String()
    schemaClient := NewClientSchema(apiURL)
    topicClient := NewClientTopic(bootstrapServers)
    resp.DataSourceData = schemaClient
    resp.ResourceData = schemaClient
}
```

Full code for branch - https://github.com/pixie79/terraform-provider-redpanda/blob/topic/internal/provider/provider.go

Currently topicClient is unused as I am not sure where to return it

Comment: This seems like you are trying to combine the provider `Configure` with the resource functions. Without further information, I would also imagine that you could leverage the Kafka Go SDK bindings within the resource functions to retrieve the information external to the client. This retrieval could be easier if you defined a function in another package within the provider module.

Comment: I have just been following the terraform-framework-scaffold-example project. Which was ok for one resource but then gets a bit unclear when you need to add more ..

Comment: The Terraform plugin framework guides are not super great, and it is helpful if you already worked with SDKv2 or v1, and/or developed Packer and Vault plugins (they are similar). I would reference the major providers (e.g. AWS) specifically for code that has already transitioned to the plugin framework. There is an effort underway to update the docs for the plugin framework `types` package, but unsure if that includes the other packages also. Either way I would still recommend my original advice especially regarding using the Kafka Go bindings instead of developing your own.

Comment: Sorry, I think what you have said makes a bit more sense now, I did not intend to write my own Kafka bindings I was going to make use of https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go

I think I understand you are saying I should wrap that as a sub package and probably move the schema client to a sub package as well, then use this as the glue. I did look at the AWS one but unfortunately I think that was a bit too complicated for an example with my level of GO skill :)

Comment: I have refactored it a bit and I think I have the resources now sorted to a point where I could use again. But I can not work out how to pass the provider config down to the individual resources now? 

updated provider configure and schema_registry_data_source

https://github.com/pixie79/terraform-provider-redpanda/blob/6d94fab58ac7e0f6a84426f3fb4f881056d1cf26/internal/provider/provider.go#L43

Answer (score 0):

The key to the `DataSourceData` and `ResourceData` variables is that they are type `any` - providers can put whatever they want in there.

We could use collection types that can hold multiple clients, or a custom `struct` with additional configuration if required. In your case, you would create a Kafka-client and a Schema Registry client in your provider `Configure` method and combine them into an aggregate object before assigning it to the `ResourceData` and `DataSourceData`. Then the `*_resource` and `*_datasource` `Configure` methods will be able to extract the client they require during the CRUD operations.

Note the current definition of `ConfigureRequest`:

```golang
// ConfigureResponse represents a response to a
// ConfigureRequest. An instance of this response struct is supplied as
// an argument to the provider's Configure function, in which the provider
// should set values on the ConfigureResponse as appropriate.
type ConfigureResponse struct {
    // DataSourceData is provider-defined data, clients, etc. that is passed
    // to [datasource.ConfigureRequest.ProviderData] for each DataSource type
    // that implements the Configure method.
    DataSourceData any

    // Diagnostics report errors or warnings related to configuring the
    // provider. An empty slice indicates success, with no warnings or
    // errors generated.
    Diagnostics diag.Diagnostics

    // ResourceData is provider-defined data, clients, etc. that is passed
    // to [resource.ConfigureRequest.ProviderData] for each Resource type
    // that implements the Configure method.
    ResourceData any
}
```

link: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-framework/blob/41190b2b4853c1364c66e062ed3f232283ef02bf/provider/configure.go